# How to deal with sum of $4^i$, from i to n, when the base isn't $2$?

Tags: summation, computational-complexity

So guys, this is regarding complexity of algorithms.
I'm trying to simplify:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}4^i$$

But I only know the simplification for $2^i$, from $1$ to $n$ (which is $2^{(i+1)}-2$.

Please can anyone guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that for the [**geometric series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) for $|r|\neq 1$

$$\sum_{\color{red}{i=0}}^{n} r^i=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$

indeed is easy to verify that

$$(1+r+r^2+\ldots+r^n)(r-1)=r^{n+1}-1$$

Comment: This is very simple and I feel stupid. Thank you, however I still want to know what the other guy did to solve this

Comment: @edwardlocke It is very simple if you know that otherwise it is not at all. Those kind of knowledge is originated from a great effort of the humanity throughout many centuries! Keep attention to the fact that the given formula starts from 0 and therefore you need to adjust the final result since your one is starting form 1. What is your result?

Comment: @edwardlocke Refer to the link I've given for more details on geometric series.

Comment: thank you for your help the result would be 4/3(4^n -1)

Comment: @edwardlocke Yes exactly! Well done. You are welcome, Bye

Answer (score 3):

Let $S =\sum_{i=1}^n4^i$. Multiply both sides by 4 to get:

$S \cdot 4 = \sum_{i=2}^{n+1}4^i$

Subtract one from the other to get:

$S = \frac{4^{n+1}-4}{3}$

Comment: I didn't understand your answer sir, can you show the steps where you change the sum's addends and subtract one from the other?

Comment: @edwardlocke $S=1+4+16+ \dots +4^n$ and $4S=4+16+64 +\dots 4^{n+1}$ and when you subtract most of the terms drop out. Always best if you don't understand how sums work to write out a few terms explicitly.

Comment: I see it now, thank you

Comment: @MarkBennet It should be $S=4+16+...+4^n$ and $4S=!6+64+...+4^{n+1}$ but itis a detail of course.

Comment: @edwardlocke As Mark has explained, after the correctionnoticed, we are taking here $3S=4S-S=4^{n+1}-4$ from which the result follows. That's a nice trick to show the formula similar to the one obtined by $(1+r+...+r^n)(r-1)=r^{n+1}-1$.

Comment: @gimusi Indeed. And that is why you write the thing out with care!